# How do I use natbib to add a possessive 's to multiple citations by the same authors?

Tags: citing, natbib, apacite

I'm using the package `apacite` with the option `natbibapa` for my in-text citations and reference list management, and so far it has worked fine, but I'm having trouble when I want to cite two sources by the same authors + add a possessive 's. I have the following solution for adding 's to my citations when there is only one author:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\newcommand\cites[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s\ (\citeyear{#1})}
```

When I wish to write e.g. "Smith and Johnson's (2011, 2015)", however, I write the following into my text:

`\cites{SmithJohnson2011,SmithJohnson2015}`

But what I end up with is "Smith and Johnson; Smith and Johnson's (2011, 2015)". I'm not sure how to redefine a command to get the right format when including more papers by the same authors. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0):

To handle general cases, I think that `\cites` needs to take 2 separate arguments, as in

```
\newcommand\cites[2]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyearpar{#2}}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{sj2011,author="Susan Smith and Janine Johnson", title="Thoughts 1", year=2011}
@misc{sj2015,author="Susan Smith and Janine Johnson", title="Thoughts 2", year=2015}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\newcommand\cites[2]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyearpar{#2}}

\begin{document}
\cites{sj2011}{sj2011,sj2015}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```